# Floating box css

Tags: css

I have a Joomla site with K2 component. And I have a bad look "issue". Please see the image:

[Css box foating problem](http://hunshooting.hu/css_float.jpg)

Here is a part from the css file what I think that it applies to here:

```
/* --- Item groups --- */
div.itemList {}
div#itemListLeading {}
div#itemListPrimary {}
div#itemListSecondary {}
div#itemListLinks {background:#f7fafe;border:1px solid #ddd;margin:8px 0;padding:8px;}

div.itemContainer {float:left;}
div.itemContainerLast {} /* this class is appended to the last container on each row     of items (useful when you want to set 0 padding/margin to the last container) */

/* --- Item block for each item group --- */
div.catItemView {padding:4px;} /* this is the item container for this view - we add a generic padding so that items don't get stuck with each other */

/* Additional class appended to the element above for further styling per group item */
div.groupLeading {}
div.groupPrimary {}
div.groupSecondary {}
div.groupLinks {padding:0;margin:0;}

div.catItemIsFeatured {background:#ddd;border:1px dotted; padding:3px;margin:1px;} /* Attach a class for each featured item */
```

So, I like the right side look. Thank you!

Comment: You can't get anything that looks like that with pure CSS.  Flexbox could do it, but the elements will be in a different order.

Comment: You might check out [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why CSS failed to achieve the results desired is because CSS only cares about horizontal position, i.e. everything is laid out horizontally first, and then vertically. Therefore, the next float on the subsequent row will only be positioned below the tallest element in the first row float, therefore leaving unfilled vertical spaces when the previous row of floats have containers with shorter heights.

I'd recommend jQuery Masonry :) http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `column-count` to achieve the required look. Keep in mind that the order of the items will be different from when you float.

Float:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Columns:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Simply set `column-count: 2` on the parent of the items.

Note that it doesn't work in all browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=column

Comment: Also note that the elements are in a different order.

Comment: Yea, that's why I clearly described that using the numbers as well as this sentence: "Keep in mind that the order of the items will be different from when you float".